# JavaScript error and database update

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem with my database and doing the update of it. I have a database table stock with 5 columns (stock_id, p_id, brand_id, cat_id, availability). I want to do an update from the frontend. So when the popup show up and I fill in the form, UPDATE doesn't work. I have 3 files. First one stock.php that read database and works fine. the seconf one that open if you click edit looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
include ( 'config.php' );
require_once( 'class.db.php' );

$database = DB::getInstance();

if($_POST['rowid']) {
    $id = $_POST['rowid']; //escape string

    $query = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stock_id = $id";
    $results = $database->get_results( $query );
    foreach( $results as $row ){
        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
        $brand_id = $row['brand_id'];
        $p_id = $row['p_id'];
        ?>

        <form method="post" name="form">
            <input id="stock_id" name="stock_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['stock_id'];?>"/>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">CATEGORY</label>
                    <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        $qex = "SELECT * FROM category";
                        $rex = $database->get_results( $qex );
                        foreach( $rex as $rowex ) {
                            ?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $rowex['cat_id']; ?>"<?php
                            if ($cat_id == $rowex['cat_id'])
                                echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $rowex['cat_name'];?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">BRAND</label>
                    <select id="brand" name="brand" class="switchable form-control">
                        <?php
                        $qex = "SELECT * FROM brand";
                        $rex = $database->get_results( $qex );
                        foreach( $rex as $rowex ) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowex['brand_id']; ?>"<?php
                            if ($brand_id == $rowex['brand_id'])
                                echo 'selected'; ?> class="brand_<?php echo $rowex['cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $rowex['brand_name'];?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">PRODUCT NAME</label>
                    <select id="product" name="product" class="switchable form-control">
                        <?php
                        $qex = "SELECT * FROM product";
                        $rex = $database->get_results( $qex );
                        foreach( $rex as $rowex ) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowex['product_id']; ?>"<?php
                            if ($product_id == $rowex['product_id'])
                                echo 'selected'; ?> class="product_<?php echo $rowex['brand_id'];?>"><?php echo $rowex['product_name'];?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">IN STOCK</label>
                    <input type="number" id="availability" name="availability" value="<?php echo $row['availability'];?>" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Update Data" class="pull-right btn btn-primary submit" style="margin-right:15px;"/>
                <span class="pull-left error" style="display:none;margin-left:15px;"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
                <span class="pull-left success" style="display:none;margin-left:15px;"> Data updated!</span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(function() {
                $(".submit").click(function() {
                    var stock_id = $("#stock_id").val();
                    var category = $('select[name="category"]').val()
                    var brand = $('select[name="brand"]').val()
                    var product = $('select[name="product"]').val()
                    var availability = $("#availability").val();

                    var dataString =
                            'stock_id='+ stock_id +
                            '&brand=' + brand +
                            '&category=' + category +
                            '&product=' + product +
                            '&availability=' + availability
                        ;

                    if(
                        stock_id=='' ||
                        brand=='' ||
                        category=='' ||
                        product=='' ||
                        availability==''
                    ){
                        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "update-stock.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            success: function(){
                                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });


            $("#category").change(function () {
                if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                    $(this).data('options', $('select.switchable option').clone());
                }
                var id = $(this).val();
                var that = this;
                $("select.switchable").each(function () {
                    var thisname = $(this).attr('name');
                    var theseoptions = $(that).data('options').filter('.' + thisname + '_' + id);
                    $(this).html(theseoptions);
                });
            });
            //then fire it off once to display the correct elements
            $('#category').trigger('change');

        });/** Document Ready Functions END **/
    </script>

<?php  } ?>
```

This is my code for update-stock.php that supposed to be updating the database:

```
<?php

session_start();
include ( 'config.php' );
require_once( 'class.db.php' );

$database = DB::getInstance();

if($_POST) {
    $stock_id = $_POST['stock_id'];
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $availability = $_POST['availability'];


    $update = array(
        'p_id' => $product,
        'brand_id' => $brand,
        'cat_id' => $cat,
        'availability' => $availability
    );

    $where_clause = array(
        'stock_id' => $stock_id
    );

    $updated = $database->update( 'stock', $update, $where_clause, 1 );
}
?>
```

I have a 2 problems.

1. Update doesn't work at all. I am just getting the message **Please Enter Valid Data**
2. My form doesn't show up the correct value of the PRODUCT NAME. Example: In the database and my main table that read information from database product name is 2.1.1 but when I click on edit and open my pop-up form that show up 2.1.3 for example.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

This one works PERFECT fetch_brand.php:

```
    <?php

session_start();
include ( 'config.php' );
require_once( 'class.db.php' );

$database = DB::getInstance();

if($_POST['rowid']) {
    $id = $_POST['rowid']; //escape string

    $query = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE brand_id = $id";
    $results = $database->get_results( $query );
    foreach( $results as $row ){
      $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
      ?>



<form method="post" name="form">
  <input id="brand_id" name="brand_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['brand_id'];?>"/>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">CATEGORY</label>
            <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
            <?php
            $qex = "SELECT * FROM category";
            $rex = $database->get_results( $qex );
            foreach( $rex as $rowex ) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rowex['cat_id']; ?>"<?php
            if ($cat_id == $rowex['cat_id'])
            echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $rowex['cat_name'];?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">BRAND NAME</label>
      <input type="text" id="brand_name" name="brand_name" value="<?php echo $row['brand_name'];?>" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Update Data" class="pull-right btn btn-primary submit" style="margin-right:15px;"/>
<span class="pull-left error" style="display:none;margin-left:15px;"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="pull-left success" style="display:none;margin-left:15px;"> Data updated!</span>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
</form>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var brand_id = $("#brand_id").val();
var brand_name = $("#brand_name").val();
var category = $('select[name="category"]').val()


var dataString =
'brand_id='+ brand_id +
'&brand_name=' + brand_name +
'&category=' + category
;

if(
  brand_id=='' ||
  brand_name=='' ||
  category==''
){
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update-brand.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});




  });/** Document Ready Functions END **/
  </script>

<?php  } ?>
```

update-product.php :

```
<?php

session_start();
include ( 'config.php' );
require_once( 'class.db.php' );

$database = DB::getInstance();

if($_POST) {
  $p_id = $_POST['p_id'];
  $brand = $_POST['brand'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $product = $_POST['product'];


  $update = array(
    'product_name' => $product,
    'brand_id' => $brand,
    'cat_id' => $cat
  );

  $where_clause = array(
    'p_id' => $p_id
  );

  $updated = $database->update( 'product', $update, $where_clause, 1 );
  }
?>
```

This one works excellent! So I am pretty sure that I made a mistake in my code for the stock.

Comment: What's in  class.db.php?

Comment: PHP MySQLi wrapper class to handle common database queries and operations

Comment: After a cursory glance, it looks like your issue is in the DB class somewhere.  Don't know for certain without seeing it.

Comment: @circusdei but that works perfect if I try to update brand or category or product. Just doesn't work with stock. So I am pretty sure I made a mistake with my code in this file but I don't see it. :D

Comment: There are some mismatched variable names: ie, 'cat_id' => $cat, (the variable is $category).  I would print_r($update); and make sure that all values are being set correctly before being passed to the DB object.